# PHP function array_search() doesn't work with variable

Tags: php, arrays, string, function, search

Function `array_search` works only with digits and not with variables eg.

```
 $key = array_search(2345632, $rozm);
```

But I need it to get the number from the variable like

```
$key = array_search($ro, $rozm);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by *"it doesn't work"* ? Getting any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually works.. see here

```
<?php
$rozm=[23,54,55];
$ro=54;
echo $key = array_search($ro, $rozm); //"prints" 1
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/101618)

### Why it didn't work for you ?

Your `$ro` variable must be a string.. so just cast it like this

```
$key = array_search(intval($ro), $rozm);
```

Comment: There's no requirement that the first parameter must be a string. If there was such a requirement, then how did the first version print `1`? `array_search()` doesn't care about the type of the argument **unless** you run it with `strict` parameter set to `true` ([An exception](http://php.net/array_search) - `If needle is a string, the comparison is done in a case-sensitive manner.` - but that's not the case here) :)